# Finding the percentage rowwise

Tags: r

I have a dataframe. Is there a way to column total. For example

```
>df <- 
structure(list(Product = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Product 100", 
"Product 75", "Product 87"), class = "factor"), Product.Family = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Product.Family 43", "Product.Family 48"), class = "factor"), 
    ColA = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))


                   Product 75 Product 100 Product 87
Product Family 43      100         0             0        
Product Family 48       0         50            50

I need it in terms of percentage
```

Comment: Probably `prop.table(table(rev(df)), margin=1) * 100`, but hard to tell without the data.

Comment: Incase there are 3 columns and I need only for 2 of them . I tried with ````prop.table(table(rev(df$Product.Family,df$Product)), margin=1)*100```` but not working

Comment: @DevP Please, be more specific than "not working". In any case, if you name the columns, remove the `rev` part (just `prop.table(table(df$Product.Family,df$Product), margin=1)*100`). Also, why didn't you provide an example of your dataset as suggested in the comments?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: @RonakShah i have added dput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from `prop.table` method suggested by @nicola in comments, we can also use `table` with `rowSums` to get the ratio row-wise

```
tab <- table(df[2:1])
tab/rowSums(tab) * 100

#                   Product
#Product.Family      Product 100 Product 75 Product 87
#  Product.Family 43           0        100          0
#  Product.Family 48          50          0         50
```